# How to get day, month, year and hour, minutes, second from DateTime format?

Tags: android, date, datetime, datetime-format, android-calendar

I tried this following code but its a deprecated in android

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

try {

    Date date1 = simpleDateFormat.parse("11/20/2014 8:10:00 AM");

    Log.e("date", "" + date1.getYear());

    Log.e("month", "" + date1.getmonth());

    Log.e("year", "" + date1.getYear());

    Log.e("hour", "" + date1.getHours());

    Log.e("minutes", "" + date1.getMinutes());

    Log.e("seconds", "" + date1.getSeconds());

} catch (ParseException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Its is deprecated how to use calendar and get day, month, year?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Set calendar time using simpleDateFormat.parse() and get field value from calendar :

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
try {
     calendar.setTime(simpleDateFormat.parse("11/20/2014 8:10:00 AM"));

     Log.e("date", "" + calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

     Log.e("month", ""+calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH));

     Log.e("year", ""+calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR));

     Log.e("hour", ""+calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR));

     Log.e("minutes", ""+calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE));

     Log.e("seconds", ""+calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND));
} catch (ParseException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: month return 10 instead of 11

Comment: Yes in calnder month start from 0 to 11 so add +1 to month value