# How to obtain date,day,year,hours and minutes value from a string?

Tags: android, datetime

I have a field in mysql database of type DateTime.The value in this field is sent as a string to my android app( say in the form "2014-11-21 06:00:00") .I need to obtain year,month,day,hours and minutes value from the string and set it to a calendar instance.Please help me.

Comment: Check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27035876/how-to-get-day-month-yeaer-and-hour-minutes-and-second-from-datetime-format/27036119#27036119

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    String s = "2014-11-21 06:00:00";
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(simpleDateFormat.parse(s));
    System.out.println(calendar.getTime());
```

Answer (score 1):

To convert your String in a Date object you can use a SimpleDateFormat:

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.UK);
Date date = simpleDateFormat.parse("2014-11-21 06:00:00");
```

Then you can use a `Calendar` with the Date object you got before

```
Calendar c = Calendar.geInstance(); 
c.setTime(date);
```

and use  `c.get(Calendar.SECOND)` to get the seconds, for instance